# How to decode JSON data by hitting an API endpoint?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to decode JSON data when I hit an API endpoint.

But my codes don't work well...

How can I solve my problem?

---

Here is JSON data when I hit an endpoint.

`https://sample.com/api/test/`

*I surely checked this endpoint works well.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": 1,
        "name": "AAA"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user": 1,
        "name": "BBB"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user": 1,
        "name": "CCC"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "user": 1,
        "name": "DDD"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "user": 1,
        "name": "EEE"
    }
]
```

---

Here are the codes:

JsonModel.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Results: Codable {
    var infos:[Infos]
}

struct Infos: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var user: Int
    var name: String
}
```

AppState.swift

*I have an error where I comment out.

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine


class AppStates: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var infos:Infos?
    @Published var results:Results?

    func hitAPI() {
        
        let endpoint: String = "https://sample.com/api/test/"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.addValue("token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
        
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error calling GET")
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do{
                    let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: responseData)
                    print(results)
                }catch{
                    print("Error: did not decode") // I have an error here
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

home.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct Home: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                appState.hitAPI()
            }) {
                Text("hit API")
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

struct Home: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Home()
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

Comment: `print("Error: did not decode") // I have an error here` => `print("Error: did not decode: \(error)") // I have an error here`, and re test. Then, you should see that there is no `infos`, not `plant_name` in your JSON... `JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self` => `JSONDecoder().decode([Infos].self` and `plant_name` => `name`, or specifiy it in the CodingKeys, but still, it should be `plantName` (camelcase)

Comment: @Larme, I,m sorry, I miswrite the name and I edited the name. the names in JSON data and  struct Infos are the same.

Comment: Still, except the `plantName`, the rest should work. There is no "infos" on your JSON. That level doesn't exists. Print the error, you'll see.

Comment: @Larme, I change my code to `JSONDecoder().decode([Infos].self,` and now It works well !! Thank you for your help,